# How can some methods be triggered in java without being called at all

Tags: java

I was looking at a java snake tutorial and there was a paintComponent method being triggered even though I never saw it being called in the gamePanel class at all. I'm new to java so I'm not sure if its the super class triggering it. I just need help understanding it because I am making a project myself and I want to understand it so that I don't have to just copy paste code each time.

here's the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 50;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT)/(UNIT_SIZE*UNIT_SIZE);
    static final int DELAY = 100;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    int applesEaten;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    
    
    
    
    GamePanel(){
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void startGame() 
    {
        newApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) 
    {
        
        if(running) {
            /*
            for(int i=0;i<SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE;i++) {
                g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
                g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
            }
            */
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
        
            for(int i = 0; i< bodyParts;i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
                else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
                    //g.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255),random.nextInt(255)));
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }           
            }
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont( new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD, 40));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: "+applesEaten, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth("Score: "+applesEaten))/2, g.getFont().getSize());
        }
        else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void newApple()  
    {
        appleX = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    
    
    public void move()
    {
        for(int i = bodyParts;i>0;i--) {
            x[i] = x[i-1];
            y[i] = y[i-1];
        }
        
        switch(direction) {
        case 'U':
            y[0] = y[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'D':
            y[0] = y[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'L':
            x[0] = x[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'R':
            x[0] = x[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void checkApple()
    {
        if((x[0] == appleX) && (y[0] == appleY)) {
            bodyParts++;
            applesEaten++;
            newApple();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void checkCollisions() 
    {
        //checks if head collides with body
        for(int i = bodyParts;i>0;i--) {
            if((x[0] == x[i])&& (y[0] == y[i])) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        //check if head touches left border
        if(x[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        //check if head touches right border
        if(x[0] > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            running = false;
        }
        //check if head touches top border
        if(y[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        //check if head touches bottom border
        if(y[0] > SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            running = false;
        }
        
        if(!running) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    public void gameOver(Graphics g) 
    {
        //Score
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont( new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD, 40));
        FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Score: "+applesEaten, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics1.stringWidth("Score: "+applesEaten))/2, g.getFont().getSize());
        //Game Over text
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont( new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD, 75));
        FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Game Over", (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics2.stringWidth("Game Over"))/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
    }
    @Override
    
    
    
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        
        if(running) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                if(direction != 'R') {
                    direction = 'L';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                if(direction != 'L') {
                    direction = 'R';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                if(direction != 'D') {
                    direction = 'U';
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                if(direction != 'U') {
                    direction = 'D';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the super class which triggers it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The central idea you've missed is the notion of a **framework**.

It's just a word people use to communicate an idea, it isn't a word you'd find in the java language specification.

However, a 'framework' in the sense I use it here (and I think, how most of the community uses it), is just a library, but one where the 'flow of execution' is a back-and-forth.

In other words, this is a library:

```
Audio audio = new someCoolLibrary.AudioDecoder().decode(pathToMp3);
```

The code flow is simple. The library is just there for you to use, and when you call it, the library does stuff and returns to you. Simple code flow.

A framework is much more back and forth. For example:

```
class MyIntroPageHandler extends WebPageHandler {
    void load(...) { ... }
}

...

WebServer server = new WebServer();
server.registerHandler("/index.html", new MyIntroPageHandler());
server.start();
```

That's a framework: Your own code doesn't ever 'call' your own `load` method - instead your code runs for a while, registers some stuff with a library, then your code tells the library to run, and as part of that, the library ends up calling your `load` method, not you. Hence, lets name that library a 'framework' to highlight the back-and-forth nature of it.

The same happens here. Indeed, you never invoke `paintComponent`. Instead you register a bunch of things (in this case, widgets, such as the instance of GamePanel, which you 'register' simply by creating it. `JPanel`'s constructor ends up doing the 'registering' here (which you inherently invoke, as all constructors always end up invoking one of their parent's constructor, even if you don't see it - javac will inject a `super()` if you don't explicitly do this).

Then the framework that is swing (the UI library you're using here which is baked into java itself, but that doesn't really make a meaningful difference as far as the definition of 'framework' and 'library' are concerned in this sense) - that ends up invoking your `paintComponent`.